# hook_user_presave at user registration, how to get field_data_field (set to auto increment) to take a new and unique value

Tags: users, entities

I'm trying to force a parallel identifier (to match up legacy system requirements) to correlate to `uid` by means of a `field_data_field_foo` table.

The `field_data_field_foo` was created in the Field UI and because I couldn't see any `UNIQUE` and `AUTO_INCREMENT` options I set them both for the column `field_data_field_foo.field_foo_value` in phpMyAdmin.

I assumed this would be enough to force the issue, but in development I setup a `hook_user_presave()` function in my custom module and with a break point inside it, for `$account->field_foo` I just get undefined....

```
field_foo   Array [1]   
    und Array [0]
```

Because this is something that *must* be assigned uniquely and I'd *like* to assign at the point of registration should I be using a different hook? Or is there something else I'm missing?

Btw, it might be something more basic in Drupal that I'm missing as I'm not that experienced with it atm - i.e. due to the nature of this project, I've yet to spend time learning nodes and the like.

Comment: well, if you set the value in the database, you cant expect to see it in presave ?

Comment: so the aim is to have another number independent of uid, do i get it right ?

Comment: Yes, I want another unique number, independent of uid, which auto increments and can be assigned to every new user when they register.

Comment: try adding a [serial field](http://drupal.org/project/serial) to the user, but only ater they [support entities other than nodes](http://drupal.org/node/1333032) :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did in the end...

First I added the field to the user registration form, as one thing Drupal is great at is processing information - I did notice errors being caught so I might have to check that out.

Then I used hook_user_presave() and (managing the unique id creation seperately) passed that, overriding any existing value or adding a value if none existed.

(full details are here: [Editing user submission of user registration form with hook_user_insert() and $edit](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/47844/editing-user-submission-of-user-registration-form-with-hook-user-insert-and-e))

I will still have to manage away the users ability to insert an identifier by hiding it through CSS/JavaScript etc. but because hook_form_alter() wouldn't edit the user registration form after repeat attempts this seems the most expedient way of solving the problem.