# Editing user submission of user registration form with hook_user_insert() and $edit

Tags: users, forms

I recognize there is a similar question here:

drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/38124/hook-user-insert-get-form-values

but I've got Eclipse and XDebugger setup so I can see the variables and I am still stuck.

I provide the variables below, please note `field_foo` is a field the system has taken care of properly without my interfering, after the user submits it, `field_bar` is a field I want to change the submitted value of, it has the value `303031` when the system handles it from form submission, where the variables show "value `300501` " is my attempt to edit that value - clearly I'm editing something wrong)

```
$edit   Array [37]  
[0...30]    
    uid 63  
    field_foo   Array [1]   
        und Array [1]   
            0   Array [1]   
                value   asdasd  
                    length  6   
                    0   61  
                    1   73  
                    2   64  
                    3   61  
                    4   73  
                    5   64  
    field_bar   Array [2]   
        und Array [1]   
            0   Array [1]   
                value   303031  
        value   300501
```

Here is my code to try and set it...

```
function MY_MODULE_user_insert(&$edit, $account, $category) {

    $newBarValue = 300501;
    $edit[field_bar][value] = $newBarValue;

}
```

**PLEASE NOTE:**

I don't know if this is the case for all field_data_field Core fields but I had to use the following to get it to work:

`$edit[field_bar][und][0][value] = $newBarValue;`

This might be unique as I am working on someone else's work atm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hook_user_insert()` is invoked after the user object and all it's fields have already been committed to the database; that's why your code isn't taking effect at the moment.

There are a couple of ways you could go:

1. Use exactly the same logic in [`hook_user_presave()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.api.php/function/hook_user_presave/7), which gets called before the data is committed to the database.
2. Implement [`hook_form_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) for the registration form, add a custom validation function, and manipulate the field values in there.

Comment: Thanks, I used hook_user_presave() as for some reason hook_form_alter() was having no effect on the user registration form. Thanks a lot

Comment: Actually, that hasn't worked - hook_user_presave() certainly makes more sense, but I think it might be my array editing that is causing trouble atm. I will read up to see if for a field_data_field Core field I should be editing it in a different way. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: **PLEASE NOTE MY EXTRA BIT** when following this answer - the problem was I needed to use this: `$edit[field_bar][und][0][value] = $newBarValue;` to edit the correct part of the array